# Context Path in Jboss

Tags: jboss, contextpath

There is a war deployed in JBOSS currently. If I want to figure out the context path for the WAR in Jboss, where should I be looking at? Server.xml?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your application is packaged as a WAR file then you can create jboss-web.xml under WEB-INF folder of WAR file and specify the context-root in jboss-web.xml like this -

```
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>MyWebAppContext</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

If your application is packaged as an EAR file then you can specify context-root in META-INF/application.xml of EAR like this

```
<module>  
  <web>  
    <web-uri>MyWAR.war</web-uri>  
    <context-root>MyWebAppContext</context-root>  
  </web>  
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jboss 4.2.3 go to your jmx-console and under jboss.web you will find the application and its context path, for example:
`J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none,j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/jmx-console`

has the context path "jmx-console/"